# Android: cant play the mp3 file from the given url

Tags: java, android, url, android-emulator, media-player

I want to know about the android media player.  I have designed a media player such that it will take the url and play the song when i select the play button when i tested in my tablet it is not working if i select the button it will not play or give the error neither crashing is happening.

i have a question in mind that whether the authentication is needed like example while researching i saw the android.drm etc because i am linking the url to the server

can anyone help me in this

i have posted the code which i have used even the logcat details as well. logcat will tell about GPU so i tested in my tablet as well still i cant listen to the mp3 file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
static final String AUDIO_PATH = "url";
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void doClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.play:
        try {
          playAudio(AUDIO_PATH);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    case R.id.stop:
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        }
        break;
    }
}

private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception
{
    killMediaPlayer();

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    killMediaPlayer();
}

private void killMediaPlayer() {
    if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

main.xml file is as shown below

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextSongURL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.54"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ButtonTestPlayPause1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/play" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBarTestPlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

in logcat there are no errors as such excluding Gpu 
[image]

Comment: are you playing from sdcard or from web link ?

Comment: diplay your mp3 file path in a log, that what path you are getting?the path of your mp3 file is correct or not?

Comment: @DhwanikGandhi from url link http:///localhost/Android/music/jingle.mp3

Comment: @DhwanikGandhi can u help me

Comment: i checked it in browser it is plying the song which i have used @FarhanShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mp.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("http://www.domian.com/ola.mp3"));
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.prepare();

mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
             // Display error
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have tried this code yaar i guess it will not play but i will try  once @jms

Comment: dude this work fine thank you very much but how should i implement the play button can u tell @jms

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
           MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mp.setDataSource(url);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                mp.start();
                mp.setLooping(true);


            }
```